# How to use method as filter in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom data type `Message`:

```
function Message(body, author, date) {
    this.body = body;
    this.author = author;
    this.date = date;
    this.stars = [];
}

Message.prototype.hasStars = function() {
    return this.stars.length !== 0;
};
```

I'm also doing a repeat on an array of these messages:

```
<li ng-repeat='message in messages | orderBy:"-stars.length"'>…</li>
```

How can I add a filter to it that calls `message.hasStars()`? I tried the following but none of them had effect:

```
message in messages | filter:message.hasStars() | orderBy:"-stars.length"
message in messages | filter:message:hasStars() | orderBy:"-stars.length"
message in messages | filter:message.hasStars | orderBy:"-stars.length"
message in messages | filter:message:hasStars | orderBy:"-stars.length"
```

Comment: You need a custom filter for that

Comment: @sza This is not true. See "Words Like Jared"'s answer.

Comment: @jessegavin That is nothing but a filter. You can create a filter using `filter` module or just a function.

Comment: It's a predicate function, but it's not registered through the dependency injector in angular as a 'filter'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/DGKNN/

`filter` expects there to be an expression that evaluates to a predicate on the scope.  That is a function that takes in an element as its parameter and returns whether or not the element should be included in the collection.

In your controller:

```
$scope.hasStars = function (message) {
    return message.hasStars();
};
```

In your view:

```
<li ng-repeat='message in messages | filter:hasStars | orderBy:"-stars.length"'>...</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a assuming some service called *mySrv* to load messages into your controller.

```
myapp.controller('myCtrlr',['$scope','mySrv',function($scope,mySrv){
    $scope.messages = mySrv.getMessages();
}]); // end myCtrlr

myapp.filter('hasStars',function(){
    return function(msg){
        return msg.stars.length > 0;
    };
});
```

In the template

```
<ul ng-controller="myCtrlr">
    <li ng-repeat="message in messages | hasStars | orderBy:"-stars.length">...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you mean to not put messages on the $scope?